# Problem with angular6 when displaying data in a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm new with angular and I've been developing a login and registration system. I did the login and everything normal, but I wanted to show the data of the person who was logging in a navbar. At first, I achieved this by sending the person's data that I was logging from the REST API and saving it in the localStorage and then printing it in the navbar, the problem is that when I just started a session, I got errors in the console with an undefined name and role. To solve it, they recommended me to use Subject, which solved my problem momentarily, since when I started the session there were no errors in the console and the navbar correctly showed me the name and the role, just like when I logged out and started with a new user. Although that solution did not last long, the problem I have now is that when I give F5, everything is destroyed and the same errors return to the console, as if the name and the role did not exist, any idea how I could solve it?

Sorry for my English, I am using a translator :(

[This is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ivM.png)

APP COMPONENT:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public static updateUserStatus: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  user: any;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
      AppComponent.updateUserStatus.subscribe((res) => {
        this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datos"));
      });

  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

AuthService:

```
signUp(user) {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(this.URL + "/signup", user)
      .pipe(map((res) => res));
  }

  signIn(user): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(this.URL + "/signin", user)
      .pipe(map((res) => res));
  }
```

Login Component

```
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  user = {};
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  signIn() {
    return this.authService.signIn(this.user).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.authService.setUser(res.datos);
        this.authService.setToken(res.token);
        /*AL ASIGNAR EL TOKEN Y EL USUARIO, LE DIGO AL APP COMPONENT QUE PUEDE
        SEGUIR EJECUTANDO EL UPDATEUSERSTATUS*/
        AppComponent.updateUserStatus.next(true);
        this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
        Swal.fire(
          "Bienvenido " + res.datos.nombre_usuario,
          "Tu Rol es: " + res.datos.rol,
          "success"
        );

      },
      (err) => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Error",
          text:
            "No se ha podido iniciar sesion, verifique su correo y contraseña",
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of the `getItem()` call (typescript):

```
const settings = localStorage.getItem('key');
if (settings != null) {
  this.settings = JSON.parse(settings);
}
```

In the html template use

- something like `user?.name` to safely access the property. The `?` tells angular to handle an undefined user
- or use `*ngIf` to hide the user information as long as it is unavailable

Comment: This ? `user: any;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    const settings = localStorage.getItem("datos");
    if (settings != null) {
      this.user = JSON.parse(settings);
    }
  }`

Comment: Mi html lo tengo con un ngIf, que verifica si esta logeado o no para mostrar dichos datos. Deje así esos <li>

`<li class="nav-item" >
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active">{{user?.nombre_usuario}}</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Rol: {{user?.rol}}</a>
          </li>`

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go.       (.. and English please)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it was in English haha, but just tried that yesterday, what happened was that it did not send me all the error messages, but also pressing f5 no longer showed me the username or the role